# ¿Porque ubuntu no actualiza ni instala programas?

Tags: ubuntu

Tengo instalado ubuntu 20.04 en Windows como subsistema.
Me mudé a vivir en otro país.

Al momento de actualizar ubuntu o instalar un paquete se queda pegado y no avanza (imagen).

sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for aaleman:
0% [Connecting to usa.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com]

Comment: Probaste con poner esas URL en el navegador? te aparecen las página?. Si no es así, prueba cambiar las DNS

Comment: revisa los repositorios en el archivo sources.list y comprueba que sean los correctos